# Persist data between views

Tags: core-data, uinavigationcontroller, persist

I am developing an app in which the user enter a search word and receives results from a web service (I control the web service). The results are displayed on a uitable view and then the user can select a row and navigate to three - four level of inner details (I am using the uinavigation control).

I am wondering what is the best way to persist the data between the views.

I am currently using the application delegate to store an array of objects which I can access from everywhere in the app. It works fine but I read that it is not a good practice for the job (I am concerned about memory issues) . I tried using Core Data framework for the job but than I realized that I would have to read my web service results, and loop them one by one in order to insert them to database. I also will have to delete old data because the data I am saving is only actual for the current search. I read about p-lists and saving data to file system but could not find a real good solution for my job...
Any help will be appreciated!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: How much of what kind of data are you storing? It seems like plist files may be a good approach (you didn't really give a reason for ruling it out). You could also just store the data directly to the drive, perhaps in the cache folder.

Comment: It is an array of objects. It starts from 25 results but the user can load more (if he taps "Load 25 more". The data is passed from the web server in JSON format. I thought about the p-list solution but did not find how to do it... I have to prepare the data in the web server (and don't know how..) and I also don't know how to save the p-list once I have it. Do you have any reference for doing so?? Will my app delegate solution be problematic, considering the small amount of data the NSArray will contain? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I included the plist example in an answer, but depending on how many groups of 25 you'll allow the user to store (and if you flush out the unused groups after a certain point), doing a centralized solution isn't bad. Personally, I prefer creating a singleton object for these purposes, keeping the AppDelegate for delegate stuff.

Comment: I don't think it will be more then 150-200 records. Do you think that the app delegate / singleton solution is good for that case?

Comment: See my edits at the bottom of my answer. Essentially, without knowing more about the app, that's a really hard call to make without a lot more detail, but just remember - premature optimization is not usually a good thing.

Comment: I must decide what method to use in this early stage. If I will postpone it to later stages it could be too late / difficult to apply

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON or PLISt for communication, although binary plist is - according to apple - much faster on the phone side.

Creating a dictionary from the binary Plist is relatively simple:

```
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSPropertyListSerialization 
        propertyListFromData:data mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainers
        format:&format errorDescription:&errorString];
```

Creating it from a JSON just requires using one of the readily available JSON libraries. Once you have the dictionary, save it:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@.plist", [paths objectAtIndex:0], @"MyPlistBaseName"];    

[plist writeToFile: file atomically:NO];
```

And re-load it later:

```
NSDictionary *plist = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: file] autorelease];
```

However, If you encapsulate the access to this data in a singleton, then you can worry about optimizing the implementation if speed / memory becomes an issue. Just treat that signleton as the 'owner' of the data, with methods like `count`, `getGroup(0)` (to return a block of 25), etc. Then you can hide all the implementation details inside the object.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I will try it. Do you know how can I crate such a binary p-list on the server side (using c#?)

Comment: I'm certain there's libraries available for that, but I'm not aware of any (I haven't done c# coding since last century, if I recall)